# Accessing the values of map from its key using pointer to map

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap, dynamic-arrays, unordered-map

I want to dynamically allocate an array of pointers to an unordered_map in C++. The std::unordered map has been typedef as 'dictionary'.

```
dict_array= ( dictionary **) calloc(input_size, sizeof(dictionary*));
```

Now I want to access the individual hashmaps, and for each individual hashmap (mydict), I want to access the values using some key. like below:

```
for (int i=0; i< input_size, i++){
   dictionary *mydict= dict_array[i];
   mydict[some_key]++;  /*access the value against 'some_key' and increment it*/
}
```

But this above line to access the value against the key generates a compilation error. What would be the correct way to access it?

Comment: You are you creating pointers to standard containers?

Comment: Why are you using `calloc`?  And any mention of "dynamic arrays" in C++ will lead to the obligatory "why are you not using `std::vector`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you haven't actually allocated any `dictionary` or (`std::unordered_map`) objects yet.

The `dict_array[i]` is simply a null pointer. Thus the assignment to `mydict` also results in a null pointer. You would need to construct a `dictionary` first by invoking `dict_array[i] = new dictionary();`.

The expression `mydict[some_key]++` doesn't mean what you think it does because `mydict` is a `dictionary *` and not a `dictionary`. Thus you would need to actually dereference it first before having access to a valid `dictionary` object:

```
(*my_dict)[some_key]++
```

But again, before this would work, you need to initialize the underlying pointers.

Also, it's generally a bad idea (which often leads to undefined behavior) to mix C allocation with C++ standard objects.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth are you messing around with pointers like this?

If you really want an array of pointers, then you'll have to dereference to access the map itself:

```
(*my_dict)[some_key]++;
```

assuming you've correctly set up each pointer to point to a valid dictionary.

Or use a less insane data structure

```
std::vector<dictionary> dict_array(input_size);

dict_array[i][some_key]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

use operator[]():

```
mydict->operator[](some_key)++;
```